For Loop through filtered datatable using LINQ Select Clause?
Is it possible to loop through a filtered data table and update the items as needed?
In my 'For i As..Next' loop, I want to check the value of a specific column in the next row and if they're not equal to the column in the current row, perform some calculations. I've tried using this approach in a 'For Each' loop, but I don't believe it's possible? Also, I'm trying to only loop through records I care about (specifically the ones that result from my SelectStatement parameter) like I'm doing with my first 'For Each' loop.
Public Shared Function MyFunction(ByRef TimeDataTable As DataTable, ByRef SelectStatement As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim Units As Decimal                    ' units (hours) billed for this day
        Dim Hours As Decimal = 0.00             ' total hours minus any PTO
        Dim ProratePercent As Decimal = 0.00    ' calculated percentage; 40+ hours
        Dim NewUnits As Decimal = 0.00          ' new hours after calculating with ProratePercent

        ' prorate employee's hours for the given week
        For Each TimeRow As DataRow In TimeDataTable.Select(SelectStatement)
            Hours = (TimeRow.Item("TotalHours") - TimeRow.Item("PTOHours"))
            Units = (TimeRow.Item("Units"))

            ProratePercent = CDec(Units / Hours)
            NewUnits = (ProratePercent * (40 - TimeRow.Item("PTOHours")))
            TimeRow.Item("Units") = Math.Round(CDec(NewUnits), 2)

            'remove this before commiting to production; just to mark that this was manipulated in the import file for data comparison
            TimeRow.Item("Time Off Name") = TimeRow.Item("Time Off Name") & " (Prorated)"

            Hours = 0.00
            ProratePercent = 0.00
            NewUnits = 0.00
        Next

        ' check previous usernames; if they don't match, check if last value adds total prorated hours to 40
        For i As Integer = 0 To TimeDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim TimeRow As DataRow = TimeDataTable.Rows(i)
            Dim Username As String = TimeRow("Username").ToString()

            If i <> TimeDataTable.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                Dim nextRow As DataRow = TimeDataTable(i + 1)
                Dim NextUsername As String = nextRow("Username").ToString()
                If Username <> NextUsername And (TimeRow("TotalHours") > 40) Then
                    ' adjust the final record to equal 40 hours
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        _logger.Error("ProrateUnits function error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function

I don't like how I'm resorting to looping through every single record in the data table in this last 'For Next' loop.
Visual Studio skips over my logic whenever I try to use this:
            For i As Integer = 0 To TimeDataTable.Select(SelectStatement).Count - 1
                Dim TimeRow As DataRow = TimeDataTable.Rows(i)
                Dim Username As String = TimeRow("Username").ToString()

                If i <> TimeDataTable.Select(SelectStatement).Count - 1 Then
                    Dim nextRow As DataRow = TimeDataTable(i + 1)
                    Dim NextUsername As String = nextRow("Username").ToString()
                    If Username <> NextUsername And (TimeRow("TotalHours") > 40) Then
                        ' adjust the final record to equal 40 hours
                    End If
                End If
            Next


With tablewoth sat and the select s you use everything is subjective

probably you should call TimeDataTable.Select(SelectStatement) once, which I think returns an array, and work on that array rather than calling it repeatedly, making new arrays. I am not sure of the right approach to then update the table though since I don't use these types; I would have to experiment with them to figure it out more.

@DaveCousineau I also had that thought. My problem is, I don't know how to communicate any updated rows/values to the original datatable? After this function is called, we pass the datatable back so it can be converted into a text file.

I think you should just be able to write to the DataRows even if you repeatedly filter. The same way that you index a row with a column name to get the value in that column, you should be able to write a value to the row with a column name. I see that you omit that part of your code. It would be TimeRow("TotalHours") = 40 or something like that. When you say that VS "skips over your logic", what do you mean? Maybe you are filtering away all rows and have nothing to iterate over? You should call Select once, save the value, and check if the results are what you expect them to be.
